# Firebase Cloud Messaging notification not visible on device however onMessageReceived is executing

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am not sure if this is a bug or there is something missing or device setting. However it looks fine to me and checked many posts. Let me try to explain from scratch.

My requirement is a customer (e.g. User A1) will do a service booking of a service provider(e.g. 'User B'). Whenever there is a booking from customer for service provider's ('User B') service, there should be a firebase notification to service provider (User B).

I am new to Android, so easy way to achieve this is also welcome. However I am trying to achieve this with firebase cloud messaging with topic subscription. Where service provider is always subscribed to a topic. Customer will subscribe to topic dynamically, send notification to topic using Retrofit, and unsubscribe from topic. So in result, customer and service provider both will get the notification.

1. At this moment a static Topic subscription is defined from app which will be changed later to dynamic
2. A Retrofit is calling `https://fcm.googleapis.com/topics/myTopic` to send notification
3. A 200 response is also coming back and onMessageReceived method is also called on customer instance *but there is no notification on any instance.*
4. notification to device from Firebase control is working fine. which means, device is not having any issue.

**Activity code which is sending notification:**

```
package www.temp.com.bookyourslot;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Model.BookingNotificationData;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Model.Posts;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Model.PushBookingNotification;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Retro.BookYourSlotNotiicationAPI;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Retro.JsonPlaceHolderAPI;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.databinding.ActivityChooseSlotBinding;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.databinding.ActivityPostsBinding;

public class PostsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String TAG = "PostsActivity";
    ActivityPostsBinding activityPostsBinding;
    JsonPlaceHolderAPI jsonPlaceHolderAPI;
    BookYourSlotNotiicationAPI bookYourSlotNotiicationAPI;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts);

        activityPostsBinding = ActivityPostsBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        View view = activityPostsBinding.getRoot();
        setContentView(view);

        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("myTopic")
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        //String msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribed);
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Subscription is not successful");
                            //msg = getString(R.string.msg_subscribe_failed);
                            Toast.makeText(PostsActivity.this, "not successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            //Log.d(TAG, msg);
                            Toast.makeText(PostsActivity.this, "Successfully subscribed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        bookYourSlotNotiicationAPI = retrofit.create(BookYourSlotNotiicationAPI.class);

        activityPostsBinding.postsSendRequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendNotification();
            }
        });


    }

     public void sendNotification(){

        PushBookingNotification pushBookingNotification=new PushBookingNotification(
                new BookingNotificationData("First Title","First Message"),
                "/topics/myTopic");
        Call<PushBookingNotification> call = bookYourSlotNotiicationAPI.sendNotification(pushBookingNotification);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<PushBookingNotification>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<PushBookingNotification> call, Response<PushBookingNotification> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    activityPostsBinding.postResultsTV.setText("Code : " + response.code());
                    return;
                }
                //PushBookingNotification notificationResponse = response.body();
                String content = "";
                content += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
                content += "Code: " + response.raw().toString() + "\n";

                activityPostsBinding.postResultsTV.setText(content);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<PushBookingNotification> call, Throwable t) {
                activityPostsBinding.postResultsTV.setText(t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Message Service class:**

```
package www.temp.com.bookyourslot.FirebaseMessaging;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private String TAG = "MessagingService";
    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String s) {
        super.onNewToken(s);

        Log.d(TAG, "onNewToken: " + s);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // ...

        // TODO(developer): Handle FCM messages here.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        Log.d(TAG, "onMessageReceived: " + remoteMessage.getData().toString());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

            /* Check if data needs to be processed by long running job */
            if ( true) {
                // For long-running tasks (10 seconds or more) use Firebase Job Dispatcher.
                //scheduleJob();
            } else {
                // Handle message within 10 seconds
                //handleNow();
            }
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeletedMessages() {
        super.onDeletedMessages();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDeletedMessages: Message is delete...");
    }
}
```

**Data Classes**

```
package www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Model;

public class BookingNotificationData {
    public String title;
    public String body;

    public BookingNotificationData(String title, String body) {
        this.title = title;
        this.body = body;
    }
}



package www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Model;

public class PushBookingNotification {
    public BookingNotificationData data;
    public String to;

    public PushBookingNotification(BookingNotificationData data, String to) {
        this.data = data;
        this.to = to;
    }
}
```

**Retro Class**

```
package www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Retro;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.Headers;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Constants;
import www.temp.com.bookyourslot.Model.PushBookingNotification;

public interface BookYourSlotNotiicationAPI {

    //String BASE_URL="https://fcm.googleapi.com";
    String SERVER_KEY="AAAAXS1k7O4:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxxxx_";
    String CONTENT_TYPE="application/json";

    @Headers({"Authorization: key="+ SERVER_KEY, "Content-Type:"+CONTENT_TYPE})
    @POST("fcm/send")
    Call<PushBookingNotification> sendNotification(@Body PushBookingNotification pushBookingNotification);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While the app is in the background the firebase will automatically handle the notification. If the app in the foreground state you need to call the Local Heads up Notification and pass the data (title, body) received from the onMessageRecieved() override function.

Something like this:

```
 private void handleNotification(String title, String message) {

    if (!DeviceInfo.isAppIsInBackground(this)) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("text", message);
        notificationIntent.putExtra("title", title);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
        notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        int notificationId = 1;
        if (notificationId == Integer.MAX_VALUE - 1)
            notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notification);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you @Kaviyarasan M.
I will try soon and let you know. I thought this so as when I tried first time from firebase console I faced this issue.<br> But I doubt this time, because I tried using two apps where as one app was in background.
Still I will try your suggestion soon and let you know